# Silverlight Control won't go higher than 600, bug?

Tags: silverlight

Try this example code.  Below is the aspx page with the silverlight control, and below that is the xaml code for the grid with colored rows.  Notice that the grid has 8 rows of 100 height each, but only the first 6 rows show up.  I can't get any control to show larger than 600.

---

aspx code

---

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:Silverlight ID="Xaml1" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/x.xap" MinimumVersion="2.0.31005.0" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
        </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

XAML Code

---

```
<UserControl xmlns:my1="clr- namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Data"  x:Class="x.Test"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
Width="400" Height="Auto">
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition  Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Grid.Row="0" Fill="Green"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="1" Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" Fill="Blue" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="3" Fill="Orange"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="4" Fill="Yellow" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="5" Fill="Black" />
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="6" Fill="Aqua"/>
    <Rectangle Grid.Row="7" Fill="Olive"/>

</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Ideas?

Comment: You already asked this in a different post. Don't.

Comment: I am aware of that.  When I posted it the first time it only showed part of the code because (I thought) I didn't format it correctly to show all of the code.  So I posted it again with the correct formatting.  How can I remove this post?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your XAML and ASPX, it works for me; I can see all the three rows. While creating a new Silverlight project, VS adds this ASPX -

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.Silverlight" Namespace="System.Web.UI.SilverlightControls"
        TagPrefix="asp" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="height:100%;">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>SilverlightApplication1</title>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%;margin:0;">
        <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%;">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <div  style="height:100%;">
                <asp:Silverlight ID="Xaml1" runat="server" Source="~/ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap" MinimumVersion="2.0.31005.0" Width="100%" Height="100%" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Can you try the above ASPX?

HTH,
indy

Comment: Indy, thanks for your reply, but you are supposed to see 8 rows, not 3.  That is my point the controls cuts off at height of 600.

Comment: That is the aspx I started with and it does not work either.  Did you try it?  Did you see 8 rows?